# Is correct tense used?

Tags: tense, present-tense, perfect-constructions

> I have talked with Tom and I found this project very interesting.

To add some context : 
I talked with Tom about one hour ago via phone and he told me about the project.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. You could also just use: "I talked with Tom..."

Comment: So I can use first part in present perfect and the second part of the sentence in past simple ? How will the meaning change if I write the second part with past simple as well ?

Comment: I think you mean the first one. If you say *I talked ... and I found*, those are actions that happened one after another. They don't show relevance in the present.

Comment: @Monx Please write the sentence you are thinking of, it will be much simpler to help

Comment: IMHO, this question is not a proofreading request. It's a genuine ELL question, even though it's short, and no obvious evidence of research has been provided. The context is clear enough, and it's rather clear that the OP focuses on two tense+aspects: the simple past vs. the present perfect. I wish it wouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to tell someone that you spoke with Tom about the project not long ago and your current opinion is that the project is interesting:

> **I've talked** with Tom about the project and **find** it interesting.

If you don't wish to say that you find it interesting at this moment (maybe you have found a more interesting project after speaking with *Mike*):

> I **talked** with Tom about the project and **found** it interesting.

Maybe you wish to say that you're no longer interested in Tom's project, after hearing from Mike about his more interesting project:

> I **talked** with Tom about the project. I **had found** it interesting, but 
>   then Mike's project **came** along, and now I **would** rather **work** on Mike's project instead.